# How to do a Contains(Description, 'a') Search in SQL like Like'%a%'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a large sql table with a column that stores short sentences. I need to implement a search when a user types a character/characters/word, the query would return the results quickly. I have implemented a full text search using MS SQL.

How to do a Contains(Description, 'a') Search in SQL like Like'%a%'

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE CONTAINS(Description 'a')
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Description LIKE '%a%'
```

If a full text search does not support this, how should I play around with this and improve the speed of the query?

Comment: Full text search is not a replacement for `like`.  It looks for words.

Comment: Right. @GordonLinoff but is it possible? I wanted the search to be fast and implemented a full text search.

Comment: . . No.  Searching for substrings within a word is not possible.  Searching for words that begin with a particular substring is possible.

Comment: Thanks! Any suggestions to make a search faster then. I want it to be like someone types a character and returns the search fast?

Comment: You only need to search what was returned from the prior character search.  So store that result set (if its below a max size) and search within it LIKE '%a%' .  Else if no prior result stored, then search LIKE the cumulative string up til now.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE PATINDEX ('%a%',description)  !=0
```